# Visual Basic: FTP Download

Tags: vb.net, ftp

I have tried different codes and non of them works for downloading a file from example DriveHQ.

But i do manage to upload so the Host seems to be fine.

EDIT*

```
sub()
  GetFile("downloadme.txt", "DESKTOP")
    End Sub

    Public Function GetFile(ByVal Name As String, ByVal DestFile As String) As Boolean
        Dim oFTP As FtpWebRequest = CType(FtpWebRequest.Create("ftp://ftp.drivehq.com/" & "" & Name), FtpWebRequest)
        oFTP.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("user", "passw")
        oFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile
        oFTP.KeepAlive = KeepAlive
        ' oFTP.EnableSsl = UseSSL
        ' If UseSSL Then ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = New RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(AddressOf ValidateServerCertificate)
        oFTP.UseBinary = True
        Dim response As FtpWebResponse = CType(oFTP.GetResponse, FtpWebResponse)
        Dim responseStream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream
        Dim fs As New FileStream(DestFile, FileMode.Create)
        Dim buffer(2047) As Byte
        Dim read As Integer = 1
        While read <> 0
            read = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
            fs.Write(buffer, 0, read)
        End While
        responseStream.Close()
        fs.Flush()
        fs.Close()
        responseStream.Close()
        response.Close()
        oFTP = Nothing
        Return True
    End Function

    Public Function ValidateServerCertificate(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal certificate As X509Certificate, ByVal chain As X509Chain, ByVal sslPolicyErrors As SslPolicyErrors) As Boolean
        If sslPolicyErrors = sslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateChainErrors Then
            Return False
        ElseIf sslPolicyErrors = sslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateNameMismatch Then
            Dim z As System.Security.Policy.Zone = System.Security.Policy.Zone.CreateFromUrl(CType(sender, HttpWebRequest).RequestUri.ToString)
            If z.SecurityZone = System.Security.SecurityZone.Intranet Or z.SecurityZone = System.Security.SecurityZone.MyComputer Then
                Return True
            End If
            Return False
        End If
        Return True
    End Function
```

//Simon

Comment: Can you post some code that you've tried, so we can steer you in the right direction?

Comment: @carmstrong tell me if you get it right

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting an error message or does it just not do what you expect it to do? You're creating a FileStream and pointing it to a file called `DESKTOP`, is this what you actually intended to do or was this just an example?

Comment: I get a runtime error. Error 530: your not logged in but I am :(

Comment: Your code is valid, I just tested it against my FTP server with a valid username and password. `(530) Not logged in` means invalid username/password.

Comment: @Chris-Haas im sure i have a valid username and password for sure cause i can log in on the website

Comment: @user564612, not to stress the point but have you confirmed that the username and password are valid from an FTP client (FileZilla, CuteFtp, etc? You might also get a 530 if you don't have read permission on your home directory.